# Trying to access array offset on value of type null but something wrong

Tags: php

It shows this problem when I added the remark part of evaluation

[image]

```
<div class="clearfix mt-3"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="remarks">Remarks</label>
    <textarea name="remarks" id="remarks" class="form-control">
        <?php echo isset($q_arr[$row['id']]['remarks']) ? $q_arr[$row['id']]['remarks'] : '' ?>
    </textarea>
```

I don't know how fix it but somehow I think my database where remarks should doesn't define.

It may have some database or PHP problem that I forgot

Comment: Welcome to SO! Currently there is not enough in the question for us to help you, you should edit your question to include debugging details: what's the content of `$q_arr` and `$row`, what are they supposed to be, and if needed, how do you retreive their value? The error tells that either `$row`, `$q_arr` or `$q_arr[$row['id']]` is null, but without details we can't say which one

Comment: do `var_dump($q_arr);` as well as `var_dump($row);` and show us the values. then only we can help you

Comment: While we wait for an [edit] on the question, the community is responsible for closing this page as Needs Debugging Details.  Then once clarified, your question will be a duplicate of some page on Stack Overflow-- so it will never be reopened.  Hopefully this experience will help you to better diagnose problems before asking for help.